How do i resolve error while using mocha and proxyqure with error message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'require')
I am experiencing an error with test suite while trying to stub out a method that queries sql db:below is the code i wrote but i keep getting error:     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'require') on the line of proxyquire
   import { expect } from "chai";
   import { mockReq, mockRes } from "sinon-express-mock";
   import proxyquire from "proxyquire";
   import sinon from "sinon";
   // import executeQuery from "../src/Utils/Db/index"
   // import roles from "../src/Routes/Roles"

   describe("Roles API", () => {
   afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
   });

  it("should return roles on GET /roles", async () => {
    const req = mockReq();
    const res = mockRes();

    // Stub executeQuery function to return some data
    const executeQuery = sinon
      .stub()
      .resolves({ recordset: [{ id: 1, roleName: "Admin" }] });

    const rolesRouterWithStub = proxyquire("../src/Routes/Roles", {
      "../src/Utils/Db/index": { default: executeQuery },
    }).default;

    await rolesRouterWithStub(req, res);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(executeQuery);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(executeQuery, "SELECT * FROM Roles");

    expect(res.send.calledOnceWithExactly([{ id: 1, roleName: 'Admin' }])).toBeTruthy();
  });
  });

